# How to recovery SuperMicro motherboard

Tags: bios, supermicro

I have SuperMicro X8DTU-F motherboard with 2x Intel Xeon E5630 2530 Mhz. Before production setup I wanted to update BIOS. SuperMicros' site proposition me 2 files:

BIOS File Name: X8DTU2_803.zip
Micro Code Update Tool: SMCI_MCU_Pkg_v1.0.1_X8DP.zip

I created boot USB flash drive with its. While BIOS upgade I get error in BAT-file, not remember exactly what error. But SMCI_MCU.exe from SMCI_MCU_Pkg_v1.0.1_X8DP.zip was completed successfully.

After reboot I got black screen. My server does not start up. 
How to recovery my server?

Comment: Try again for redownloading, and flashing. Something could have happened during download that corrupted it. If the same problem occurs then go down a revision to another version until you find a stable one that works

Comment: ook, but server doesn't start up...